# Paraview points to Blender

Tags: rendering, particles

I am using Blender and have some problems rendering the fluids
I want to use the Paraview to visualize the particles and export it to Blender and render it. But the x3d file I imported into Blender always remain black and the color can not be changed. I think I might have some problems calculating the surface norms, but I don't know how to calculate the norms of particles correctly.
I'm so interested to hear from your advices[image: The orange object is the one I want to render]

Comment: What render engine are you using? Did you apply any materials? Are any textures involved? Is there any lighting in your scene? Could you post some screenshots of the render results? Please edit your question and provide some more details, possibly some screenshots of the mesh rendered/shaded/and in wireframe in the viewport.

Comment: So that image tells almost nothing as all we can see is the outline of the object, not the structure, material, or anything useful.